# Width of absolute table is not responsive when has image inside

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-position

I have the follwoing setup: A reltive parent, an absolute table with `width:50%` inside it and an Image inside the cell of table. The image width is set to 60%. When I test the template in responsive mode, when the window width reaches about 560px the table starts taking more than 50%. When I omit the image it takes 50%. Whats wrong with that setup?

```css
.parent{
  width:100%;
  height:120px;
  background:#ff8800;
  position:relative;
}
.child{  
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  background:#0000ff;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <table class="child">
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center">
        <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" style="width:60%">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: On this snippet, I can see no problem...

Comment: Which browser you are using? @Derek.W

Comment: I am on mozilla firefox.

Comment: OK! It seems Chrome and FireFox have different rendering logic! @Derek.W

Answer (score 1):

Set `max-width` css attribute on the table and it will work on both web browsers.

```
.child {
  ...

  max-width: 50%;
}
```